Spring boot transaction exception UnexpectedRollbackException always propagates
I have the following two services:
@Slf4j
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class NextIdService {

    private final NextIdRepository nextIdRepository;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public int getNextId(int id) {
        try {
            NextId nextId = nextIdRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
            if (nextid != null) {
                nextId.setNext(nextId.getNext() + 1);
                nextIdRepository.saveAndFlush(nextId);
                return nextId.getNext();
            } else {
                log.debug("No record found for id...");
                return -1;
            }
        } catch (PessimisticLockingFailureException e) {
            // nextid record is locked
            log.warn("Next id record is locked...");
            return -1;
        }
    }
}

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ItemService {

    private final ItemRepository ItemRepository;
    private final NextIdService nextIdService;

    public record ItemDto(Integer id, LocalDate date, LocalTime time, String message, String terminal) {

    }

    @Transactional
    public ItemDto create(String message, String terminal) {
        int nextId = nextId = nextIdService.getNextId(13);
        if (nextId == -1) throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                "Unable to get next id!");
        Item item = new item();
        item.setMessage(message);
        item.setTerminal(terminal + "_" + StringUtils.leftPad(String.valueOf(nextId), 4, "0"));
        item.setDate(LocalDate.now());
        item.setTime(LocalTime.now());
        itemRepository.saveAndFlush(item);
        return new ItemDto(item.getId(), item.getDate(), item.getTime(), item.getMessage(),
                item.getTerminal());
    }
}

When nextIdRepository.findById(id) throws PessimisticLockingFailureException the catch block is correctly executed, I find the message in the log file, but in the create(...) method of the ItemService service an UnexpectedRollbackException is thrown on the call nextIdService.getNextId(13) and the create(...) method is then aborted.
I also tried using parameter noRollbackForClassName = Exception.class for the @Transactionl annotation of the getNextId(id) method as follows:
 @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, noRollbackFor = Exception.class) 

but still an UnexpectedRollbackException is raised and propagated to the create(...) method.
I had to use Propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW option on the transaction to release the record immediately, after next id update, and not wait for the create(...) method of ItemService to fully release it.
I expect to be able to handle the LOCK case without raising any exceptions from the getNextId(id) method and return -1 if the value of the record cannot be updated.
